# C# Task Action with different parameters

Tags: c#, task

I'm working on a game server and currently I have this ***Announce*** class which does the job of announcing to the connected clients anything that happens in the server.

The game server is supposed to be able to hold over 400 players without troubles.

So far this is what I'm doing when trying to announce an effect on the map to all the players present:

```
public static void AnnounceMagicEffect(byte effect, UInt16 x, UInt16 y, byte z) {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                List<Player> spectators = Map.GetPlayerSpectators(x, y, z);
                foreach (Player player in spectators) {
                    Sending.SendMagicEffect(player, effect, x, y, z);
                }
            });
        }
```

Basically I will program over 50 functions that are supposed to announce something for the spectators in the game.

Is this thread safe?
Is this the right way to achieve this task?

At first I wanted to make a function like:

```
public static void AddGameTask(Action action) {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action);
}
```

But it wouldn't support parameters, as I might have to use them like:

```
AnnouncePlayerMove(Player player, Direction direction);
AnnouncePlayerSay(Player player, string text);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: More along the lines of "How can I achieve this" than about whether or not your existing code is thread safe.  To announce to "all connected parties", you can implement a SignalR hub (or a WebSockets room) and broadcast to the room.

Comment: I'm doing the announcing already, what I'm questioning is if the way I'm currently doing it is thread-safe and how to implement Action<T> to a StartNew Task

Answer (score 0):

Can't say if your code example is thread safe or not by looking at it. It depends on what the `Map.GetPlayerSpectators` and `Sending.SendMagicEffect` methods do.

You have to take a step back and consider what would happen if another task modified the memory that those methods use to generate their responses. Can another task modified the list of player spectators? Does the `Map.GetPlayerSpectators` and `Sending.SendMagicEffect` methods modify data, or do they only read data?

Changing your method `AnnounceMagicEffect` to accept any Action delegate makes it even more nebulous. Who knows if its thread safe?

When you create a task, it shares the memory that existed before the task was created with its creating task.

Take this example:

```
List<string> listOfFiles = new List<string>();
listOfFiles.Add( filename1 );
listOfFiles.Add( filename2 );
listOfFiles.Add( filename3 );

Task.Run( () =>
{
  foreach( string file in citationFiles )
    File.Delete( file );
} );

citationFiles.Clear();
```

Chances are that the files will never be deleted. The main task will clear out the List before the task ever gets started.

You need to consider multiple tasks operating on the same memory at the same time.